# How can I show custom field only on stock internal transfer or delivery order move line in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-view

I have created a custom field in `stock.move` and now I need to show it only on `Delivery Order` or `Internal Transfer` move lines.
I am trying following code but its giving me an error.
Code is:

```
    <record id="view_move_picking_tree_inherit1" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.move.tree</field>
        <field name="model">stock.move</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_move_picking_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="product_id" position="after">
                <field name="finish_item" nolabel="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('picking_id.picking_type_code', '=', 'outgoing')]}"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Error is:

```
    Uncaught Error: Unknown field picking_id.picking_type_code in domain [["picking_id.picking_type_code","=","outgoing"]]
```

Anyone please help me about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with given below

```
<field name="finish_item" nolabel="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('picking_type_id.code', '=', 'outgoing')]}"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[('picking_type_id.code', '=', 'incoming')]` if he wants to show it in Delivery Orders (outgoing) and Internal Transfers (internal)?

Comment: Its also giving me this error `Uncaught Error: Unknown field picking_type_id.code in domain [["picking_type_id.code","=","outgoing"]]`

Comment: Which view I should inherit for it?  `view_move_picking_tree` or `view_picking_form`

Comment: Hiding per condition in tree view is not possible , please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635299/dynamicly-hide-fields-and-rows-in-tree-view-odoo-9